Wazuh Anomaly detection plugin enable on docker
I have installed Wazuh (indexer, manager & dashboard) using Docker.
I am trying to get the Anomaly Detection plugin enabled in Wazuh/Opensearch installation.
How/ where do I enable this plugin?
I have tried to go into the Wazuh Dashboard docker by using
#sudo docker run -it <container ID> bash 
Here, I get this error getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND wazuh.indexer  repeatedly, but as mentioned, Wazuh Indexer container is run separately as well.
Any pointers in this regard would be extremely helpful.

Answer to this was posted on Wazuh-github. So acknowledgements to the responder @davidcr01
On the server where wazuh docker is running:
#sudo docker ps {note the wazuh dashboard container number from the output}
#sudo docker exec -it {docker container number} bash {bash prompt comes up}
bash$ /usr/share/wazuh-dashboard/bin/opensearch-dashboards-plugin install anomalyDetectionDashboards
bash$ exit
#sudo docker restart {docker container number}
#sudo -u wazuh-dashboard /usr/share/wazuh-dashboard/bin/opensearch-dashboards-plugin list (anomaly detection plugin should be listed)
